# How can I COUNT(DISTINCT) in ServiceStack Ormlite?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I'm writing a paged query in ServiceStack's OrmLite, selecting the total records and the ids of records in the page range. Assuming `query` is some arbitrary SqlExpression selecting a bunch of records:

```
var idQuery = query.SelectDistinct(r => r.Id);
var ids = Db.Column<int>(idQuery.Skip(request.Skip).Take(request.Take));
var total = Db.Count(idQuery);
```

OrmLite generates two queries, one for the ids:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

And one for the total:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
```

I'm trying to get OrmLite to generate `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Id)` for the total query, or perform an equivalent. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In previous versions of OrmLite you would need to use Custom SQL:

```
var count = db.Scalar<long>(idQuery.Select("COUNT(DISTINCT Id)"));
```

I've just added support for [Sql.CountDistinct in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/dad8a77a6d8437bc78692ff5ce6b8f7e79ee2ab4) which will let you use a Typed API:

```
var count = db.Scalar<long>(idQuery.Select(x => Sql.CountDistinct(x.Id)));
```

This change is available from v4.0.61 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Cool! Thanks mythz!